# Fuzzy checking if each item of a list is contained in a given string

Tags: python, if-statement, fuzzy-search

```
list = ['Apple','Banana','Cucumber']
string = 'The other day as I ate a bnana in the park'

for x in range(len(list)):
    if list[x] in string:
        do a little dance
```

This is the gist of my code as it stands now, though my actual string and list are much longer. The string is user submitted so I have to expect misspelling/shorthand/CAPS and short of filling my list with every misspelling I can think of or parsing each word of the string, I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

I'm looking for a fuzzy contains if statement. I've looked through fuzzywuzzy documentation and I'm not sure how to make it work in this case.

Is there any function like this?

```
threshold = 80
for x in range(len(list):
     if fuzzy.contain(list[x],string) > threshold:
         do a little dance:
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: _I've looked through fuzzywuzzy documentation and I'm not sure how to make it work in this case._ Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a `contain` method in the `fuzzywuzzy documentation`, so I came up with this. You split the phrase by words, and then compare each word in a `fuzzy` way. Depending on your special needs you should use other rating methods instead of `token_sort_ratio` and `threshold` value. You can find more information in their [github](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def fuzzy_contains_word(word, phrase, threshold):
    for phrase_word in phrase.split():
        if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(word, phrase_word) > threshold:
            return True
    return False


words = ['Apple','Banana', 'Cucumber']
user_input = 'The other day as I ate a bnana in the park'
threshold = 80

for word in words:
    if fuzzy_contains_word(word, user_input, 80):
        print(word, 'found in phrase: ', user_input)

>>> Banana found in phrase:  The other day as I ate a bnana in the park
```

Note: I got a warning from this saying you should install `python-Levenshtein` package.

Comment: This worked very well, thanks. This also makes my next problem very easy which is fuzzy finding "Apple" but not "Crab Apple". thanks again.

Comment: @GustavoCosta good! If it solved your problem, consider selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
threshold = 80
for x in range(len(list)):
     if fuzzy.WRatio(list[x],string) > threshold:
         do a little dance:
```

*Disclaimer I've never used `fuzzy` before, but that should work.

Comment: This wasnt working for me as well as I'd like before but it was due to caps issues. fuzzy.WRatio() is getting the trick done. Thanks for your help

Comment: Updated given Gustavo's feedback.